# Vuetify 3 with vue

Tags: vuetify.js, vuejs3

I have installed vue 3 with vuetify alpha version for vue 3 using vite. But almost none of the UI components works correctly. The colors are diferent, even if I copy-paste the template and script tags for the respective UI component.
For example this is how it looks for me: [image]

And this is how it looks on their website:
[image]

[image]

AM I doing something incorrectly ? Or is it really incompatible and not reliable with vue 3

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade is not very straightforward because a lot of props has been changed. And the documentation for vuetify 3 is outdated so you can't just copy and paste from the documentation. Currently, I'm a afraid that you should look into the source code to figure it out.